# Как передать значение в input из модал ?

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/Taypfoon/L525w/
Хочется по клику на ссылку в модальном окне закрыть его , передав значение id в input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Один из вариантов](http://jsfiddle.net/5XKEL/)

```
var $modal = $('#exampleModal');
$('.modal').click(function(){
    $modal.arcticmodal();
});

$('body').on('click', '#exampleModal a', function () {
    $('input').val($(this).attr('id'));
    $modal.arcticmodal('close');
});
```

Comment: Действующая модель, спасибо.
А если в модал Ajax файл с сервера ?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду: если в окне контент, который подтянулся динамически? при текущей реализации все должно работать, т.к. событие привязывается динамически (что-то вроде устаревшего live())

Comment: Или я где-то добавляю ошибку или не работает 
http://prohe.net/Lib/jQuery/Modal/ArcticModal/ajaxModal.html

Comment: вероятно, arcticmodal пересоздает весь контейнер, поэтому привязанные к контейнеру эвенты теряются. замените строчку

    $modal.on('click', 'a', function () {

на

    $('body').on('click', '#exampleModal a', function () {

Comment: Огромное спасибо !